# Error inserting values in a table

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, csv

I am reading values from a csv file and I am able to do that accurately. However, when I try to write those values in a systems db's table, I get an error saying one column doesn't exist in the table.

Logcat error:

```
E/SQLiteLog(318):      (1) table hospital has no column named zip

E/SQLiteDatabase(318): Error inserting zip=36301 avgCharges=20313 avgPayment=4895 _id=10001 address=1108 ROSS CLARK CIRCLE providerName=SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER state=AL procedure=057 - DEGENERATIVE NERVOUS SYSTEM DISORDERS W/O MCC discharges=38 city=DOTHAN

E/SQLiteDatabase(318): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table hospital has no column named zip (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO hospital(zip,avgCharges,avgPayment,_id,address,providerName,state,procedure,discharges,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

E/SQLiteDatabase(318):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Create Table query: (all fields are in TEXT for testing)

```
query = "CREATE TABLE hospital(_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, procedure TEXT, providerName TEXT,     address TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT, zip TEXT, discharges TEXT, avgCharges TEXT, avgPayment TEXT)";

db.execSQL(query);
```

I am sure there is no column type mismatch. It says it cannot find the column named ZIP. i do not understand whats happening here.

Query to insert values:
    values.put("_id", hospital.get_id());

```
    values.put("procedure", hospital.get_procedure());
    values.put("providerName", hospital.get_providerName());
    values.put("address", hospital.get_address());
    values.put("city", hospital.get_city());
    values.put("state", hospital.get_state());
    values.put("zip", hospital.get_zip());
    values.put("discharges", hospital.get_discharges());
    values.put("avgCharges", hospital.get_avgCharges());
    values.put("avgPayment", hospital.get_avgPayment());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Any ideas on what could be done here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you plz post the code where you create the table

Comment: please adapt your posted code, espacially the query and post the logcat also in the right way. It is a little bit confusing...

Comment: I tried the create and insert query myself with sample data. And it worked, I suggest you to make sure the column name is 'zip' and there is not a space with word zip

Comment: I have checked them and I am sure I have used zip only and nothing else. There aren't any spaces or anything as seen in the code above.

Comment: Are you executing your "create sql" only in your SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate? Maybe you've forgotten about onUpdate method?

Comment: Oh! I don't have an "onUpdate" method in my program. Any tutorial that I should be looking at??

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the onUpgrade method to drop and add tables whenever the schema is changed. You can look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int).

Answer (score 0):

The table needs to be dropped before adding a new column in the code.
You should clear the app data. Else uninstall the app and run it from Studio.